# Angular 2 click event callback without triggering change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, zonejs

I'm having major trouble trying to perform some logic inside a `(click)` event callback function in Angular 2 without triggering change detection.

**Why I don't want to trigger change detection**

The callback function performs a simple animated scroll to top. It effects no other components and therefore I don't need change detection to fire in every component, in fact I really don't want it to fire! Because change detection does fire in every component, the performance of the animation on mobile is extremely poor.

**What I've tried**

I know I can run code outside of the zone using

```
this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    someFunction();
})
```

This works nicely when the code you want to run outside the zone isn't invoked by a `click`, `keyup`, `keydown` event etc.

Because my component looks like...

`<button (click)="doThing()">Do that thing outside the zone!</button>`

```
doThing() {
    this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        myFunction();
    })
}
```

...`myFunction` will be run outside the zone but the `click` event will trigger change detection.

I've already implemented `OnPush` change detection strategy in as many of my components as possible.

It's important that change detection is not triggered here but I can't find a way to prevent it.

**Edit**
See this [plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/KfwVSgigTZcB34OjhyvO?p=preview) with change detection set to `OnPush` in all components. Clicking the subrow component button triggers CD in the subrow, row and app components.

Comment: have you tried to use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in that component's `@Component({})` decorator???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted, even setting the component in which the `click` event occurs to `OnPush` will still result in change detection being triggered.

**Out-of-the-box event handling**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test'
    template: `<button (click)="onClick($event)">Click me</button>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {
    
    onClick(e:Event) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            // gets run outside of Angular but parent function still triggers change detection
        });

        return false;

        /*
         * change detection always triggered
         * regardless of what happens above
         */
     }

 }
```

Most of the time this may not be a problem but when rendering and painting performance for certain functions  is essential I'm taking the approach of entirely by-passing Angular's built-in event handling. From my own experiments the following seems to be the easiest and most maintainable way to approach this.

**By-pass out-of-the-box event handling**

The idea here is to use RxJS to manually bind to whatever events I want, in this case a click, using `fromEvent`. This example also demonstrates the practice of cleaning up the event subscriptions.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subscription, fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'test'
    template: `<button #myButton>Click me</button>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private _destroyed$: Subject<null> = new Subject();

    // reference to template variable
    @ViewChild('myButton') myButton: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

    constructor(private _zone: NgZone){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscribeToMyButton();
    }

    subscribeToMyButton() {
        this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            fromEvent(this.myButton.nativeElement, 'click')
                .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
                .subscribe(e => {
                    console.log('Yayyyyy! No change detection!');
                });
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // clean up subscription
        this._destroyed$.next();
        this._destroyed$.complete();
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will be some help to others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you use `OnPush`</strike>

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

then change detection should be limited to the component where the click event happens.

You can detach the `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private dataProvider:DataProvider) {
    ref.detach();
  }
```

Change detection won't be run for this component until it is reattached.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. I'll edit the original post with a poorly formatted plnk!

Comment: `detatch()` seems to prevent change detection https://plnkr.co/edit/wVjjGhcZkqVbtsVjvZyi?p=preview.

Comment: I also tried `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event but that didn't prevent change detection to run on all components.

Comment: Likewise. I tried those two as well but to no avail. I'll look further into `detach` but right now my best option, I think, is using RxJs's `Observable.fromEvent` to manually listen to clicks on my element and run the callback outside Angular. The problem with `detach` being that as soon as I `reattach` it's going to run change detection again.

Answer (score 1):

I can show one total hack but seems it works.

**sub-row-component.ts**

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone, private app: ApplicationRef) {}

rowClick() {
  console.log('rowClick');
  var a = 4;

  let originalTick = (<any>this.app).constructor.prototype.tick;
  (<any>this.app).constructor.prototype.tick = () => console.info('tick tick tick :)');
  const subscriber = this.zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
    next: () => { 
      console.info('tick has been stopped. So we can return everything in its place');  
      subscriber.unsubscribe();
      (<any>this.app).constructor.prototype.tick = originalTick;
  }});
}
```

**[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nl8S0FIOE5rAkGxbLs4Q?p=preview)**